# Jquery Ajax - Problemas em fazer requisiçao a cada x segundos

Tags: jquery, ajax, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web que utilizo ajax para fazer requiçao de tempos em tempos para saber se houve uma nova atualizaçao, porem o meu codigo nao funciona perfeitamente. Eu sou novato em jquery e estou com dificuldades em implementar essa funcionalidade. Peguei um exemplo na net porem o meu nao atualiza a pagina.

A div que pretendo atualizar:

```
<div id="palhetas" class="card-body no-padding">
                    #{list items:palhetas, as:'p'}
                    <div class="item d-flex align-items-center">
                        <input type="hidden" name="palheta.id" value="${p?.id}" />
                        <div class="text">
                            <a href="#"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="torre">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="palheta.id" value="${p.id}" /> <font
                                    size="3">Agente: ${p.agente.nome}</font>
                            </a><font size="2"> Endereço: ${p.endereco.rua} </font><br>
                            <font size="2"> Situação: ${p.situacao} </font>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    #{/list}
                </div>
```

Script ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Services/listarPalhetas",
            beforeSend: function() {$("#palhetas").empty();$("#palhetas").append(<a href="palhetas/detalhesPalhetas?id='+i+'"><div class="item d-flex align-items-center"><div class="text"><font size="3"><center>Agente: '+data[i].agente.nome+'</center></font><font size="2">Endereço: '+data[i].endereco.rua+'</font></div></div></a>');}                    
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#palhetas").empty();         
            $("#palhetas").append(data);
        });
    }
    getData();
    setInterval(getData, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no evento de *callback* `beforeSend`. Como o *JavaScript* não está encontrando a variável `data` e `i`, o *JavaScript* finaliza a aplicação e retorna um erro.

Caso como esteja recebendo um *JSON*, você deve adicionar esse trecho dentro da função `done` ou da função de *callback* `success` (O mais recomendado).

**Exemplo:**

```
<div id="palhetas"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            /* URL */
            url: "index2.php",

            /* Retorna os dados no formato JSON */
            dataType: "json",

            /* Aciona esse evento antes da requisição */
            beforeSend: function() {
                //$("#palhetas").empty();
            },

            /* Aciona essa evento quando há sucesso da requisição */
            success: function(data) {

                $("#palhetas").html("");

                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    /* Cria o html */
                    let html   = '<a href="palhetas/detalhesPalhetas?id='+i+'">';
                        html  += '   <div class="item d-flex align-items-center">';
                        html  += '       <div class="text">';
                        html  += '           <font size="3"><center>Agente: '+data[i].agente.nome+'</center></font>';
                        html  += '           <font size="2">Endereço: '+data[i].endereco.rua+'</font>';
                        html  += '       </div>';
                        html  += '   </div>';
                        html  += '</a>';

                    /* Inclui o HTML na variável indicada */
                    $("#palhetas").append(html);
                }
            },

            /* Aciona o evento ao finalizar a requisição */
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(getData, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    getData();
});
</script>
```

> Como lembrado pelo usuário *DVD*, você também pode utilizar o `setTimeout`.

Comment: ele apresenta o seguinte erro no console do navegador: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=.
Reclamando d ponto e virgula da linha: let html  += '   <div class="item d-flex align-items-center">';

Comment: @CarlosDiego corrigido

Comment: Perfeito @Valdeir, funcionou. Mto obgdo

Comment: me tira outra duvida, desse jeito vc percebe que ele pisca na tela a cada atualizaçao, pois ele limpa a pagina e depois escreve com os dados da nova requisiçao, tem como fazer isso sem essa "piscada de tela"?

Comment: @CarlosDiego tem sim. Editei minha resposta.

Comment: agora esta vindo array[0].

Comment: @CarlosDiego corrigido.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73399/discussion-between-carlos-diego-and-valdeir-psr).

Answer (score 3):

Não use `setInterval`. O `setInterval` é um temporizador ininterrupto e vai ficar enviando requisições ao Ajax sem esperar que a requisição anterior tenha sido terminada.

> Ao usar `setInterval`, abra seu console (F12) na aba "Network" e veja o
>   gargalo de requisições quase que simultâneas. **Consequências:** site mais lento, consumo de banda desnecessária, stress do servidor etc... **Com `setTimeout`, será apenas 1 requisição a cada 5 segundos (tempo defino em 5000).**

Em vez disso, use `setTimeout` quando o retorno do Ajax estiver completo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Services/listarPalhetas",
            beforeSend: function(){
               $("#palhetas").empty();
            },
            success: function(data)
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                   $("#palhetas").append('<a href="palhetas/detalhesPalhetas?id='+i+'"><div class="item d-flex align-items-center"><div class="text"><font size="3"><center>Agente: '+data[i].agente.nome+'</center></font><font size="2">Endereço: '+data[i].endereco.rua+'</font></div></div></a>');
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
               setTimeout(getData, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
    getData();
});
```

Comment: dando o erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier na linha: $("#palhetas").append('<a href="palhetas/detalhesPalhetas?id='+i+'"><div class="item d-flex align-items-center"><div class="text"><font size="3"><center>Agente: '+data[i].agente.nome+'</center></font><font size="2">Endereço: '+data[i].endereco.rua+'</font></div></div></a>');

Comment: O que seria esse `i` em `data[i]`?

Comment: meu indice de um array de palhetas

Comment: Adicionado na resposta. É só fazer um loop.