# Problema para executar setInterval

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde

Estou testando automatizar a busca por registro ao banco de dados com o script abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/teste.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="public/js/exibi.js"></script>  -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            var refreshAutomatico = setInterval(function(){
                $('tabela').load(Teste());
              }, 5000);
        });  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div id="resposta">
                <table border="1" width="500">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Nome</th>
                              <th>Acesso</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="tabela">
                      </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(
            function Teste(){
            $.ajax({
            type:'post',  //Definimos o método HTTP usado
            dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
            url: 'consulta.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
            success: function montaTabela(dados){
            console.log(dados);
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
              //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
              $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].acesso+'</td></tr>');
            }

            
            }
          });
          });

</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Porém, está ocorrendo o erro abaixo:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Teste is not defined
>       at teste.php:15

Comment: A primeira tag `<script>` é executada e o método `Teste()` ainda não foi instanciado, logo dá esse erro. Passa o método para dentro da segunda tag `<script>`.

Comment: Coloca os teus scripts depois da tag `</body>`, e aproveita ajustar a ordem de carregamento dos teus scripts.

Comment: @Edilson tentei as duas soluções porem ainda continua dando o mesmo erro: tanto se eu colocar a function do bloco setInterval depois ou antes do bloco do ajax

Answer (score 0):

Tem muitos problemas no seu código. Primeiro que você não conseguiria acessar a função `Teste()` fora do `$(document).ready` porque a função não teria escopo no outro bloco de script.

Outro erro é que você está colocando o nome `Teste` na função anônima do `$(document).ready`, quando ela deveria ser um função dentro da `function` do `.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // <-- função anônima do .ready
   function Teste(){}
});
```

Outro erro mais grave é que você está usando dois AJAX de uma só vez: `.load` e `$.ajax`.

O método `.load()` é um AJAX simplificado do jQuery. Portanto, quando você chama o `.load()` para chamar outra função com outro AJAX, é totalmente sem sentido.

Se você quer carregar dados para dentro do elemento `#tabela`, ou você usa `.load()` ou `$.ajax`. No seu caso, como se trata de JSON, use apenas o `$.ajax` pois ele é mais completo e possui opções, ao contrário do `.load()`.

*Também não é recomendado usar `setInterval` para fazer requisições de tempo em tempo. O ideal é fazer uma requisição após a outra somente quando uma tiver sido completada ([trato disso na resposta neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277428/8063)).*

> Outra coisa é que `$(document).ready(function(){});` é o mesmo que
>   `$(function(){});`, portanto não faz sentido usar dois ao mesmo tempo.

Seu código correto ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   function Teste(){
      $.ajax({
         type:'post',       //Definimos o método HTTP usado
         dataType: 'json',  //Definimos o tipo de retorno
         url: 'consulta.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
         success: function(dados){
            console.log(dados);
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
               //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
               $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].acesso+'</td></tr>');
            }
         }
      });
   }

   var refreshAutomatico = setInterval(Teste, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Bom dia @Sam obrigado pela explicação, porem ao executar com o seu código mesmo aumentando o tempo o mesmo esta puxando a primeira vez a informação e depois ela duplica

Comment: Bom dia. Acho que tem que esvaziar antes: `$('#tabela').empty().append(....`

Comment: Creio que vc deve usar `.html()` em vez de `.append()`. Assim vc nem precisa esvaziar a tabela antes: `$('#tabela').html(...`

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que dessa forma ele puxa a informação e não duplica, porem não sei se seria a forma mais correta de executar tal código por isso fico a disposição para sugestões melhores

```js
$(function() {
 var refreshAutomatico = setInterval(function(){
  $('#tabela').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
   $.ajax({
    type:'post',  //Definimos o método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
    url: 'consulta.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    success: function montaTabela(dados){
   console.log(dados);
   for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
     //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
     $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].acesso+'</td></tr>');
   }
    }
  });
  
 }, 50000);
});
```